# How to convert NCPDP standard format message to xml format in java?

Tags: javascript, java, xml, mirth

i'm trying to find, is there any library available that convert NCPDP format message to XML format in java?. In Mirth Connect tool, there's direct option to convert NCPDP to XML using this lines:

```
var serializationProperties = SerializerFactory.getDefaultSerializationProperties('NCPDP');
SerializerFactory.getSerializer('NCPDP', serializationProperties, null).toXML(ncpdpmessage);
```

and Mirth Connect giving this functionality, so they have use some api or library in backend to convert NCPDP to XML. i want to do same, but in java.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Java's invoke dynamic (https://www.infoq.com/articles/Invokedynamic-Javas-secret-weapon) calls to JS which will provide the conversion?

Comment: it's not related to ncpdp format to xml conversion @BorisPavlović

Comment: The code snippet from your question seems like JS. Maybe it's possible to invoke it from Java using invoke dynamic.

Comment: it is like javascript, but in it they used serializedFactory which Convert NCPDP format to xml, in mirth right panel there's option to convert it, so we have to just drag and drop and i get above code.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the NCDPD message you'd like to convert or contrary a sample of the XML that can be converted to NCPDP?

Comment: still not have, if you have some sample data, then you can put in below your answer `ncpdpReader.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(source)));` so, i can process it further and it is giving some error like `Save could not be completed. Reason: Some characters cannot be mapped using "Cp1252" character encoding. Either change the encoding or remove the characters which are not supported by the "Cp1252" character encoding.`

Comment: I'm not sure what you've tried parse. This is becoming an implementation specific, if you'd like you may contact me directly to exchange files/codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mirth Connect uses its own implementation of NCPDP serializer. You may find it in datatype-ncpdp-shared.jar in the \extensions\datatype-ncpdp folder.

In short, the NCPDPSerializer.toXml() code does the following:

```
NCPDPReader ncpdpReader = new NCPDPReader(serializationSegmentDelimiter, serializationGroupDelimiter, serializationFieldDelimiter);
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
XMLPrettyPrinter serializer = new XMLPrettyPrinter(stringWriter);
ncpdpReader.setContentHandler(serializer);
ncpdpReader.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(source)));
return stringWriter.toString();
```

So if you want to utilize the same you probably need all other related Mirth libraries. Since NCPDPReader extends SAXParser and does not rely on any other Mirth packages you may try to build your own library based on that. (Check copyrights and license notes before you start doing so.)
You may also try to find other NCPDP Java parser such as JParser.

Comment: i checkout project from [here](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/fisheye/browse/~br=3.2.x/Mirth/branches/3.2.x) , it contain all the classes related to ncpdp, but i dont know how can i create own class use that classes same way as in mirth this two line do: `var serializationProperties = SerializerFactory.getDefaultSerializationProperties('NCPDP');
SerializerFactory.getSerializer('NCPDP', serializationProperties, null).toXML(ncpdpmessage);`

Comment: I posted above what `SerializerFactory.getSerializer('NCPDP', serializationProperties, null).toXML(ncpdpmessage)` does.

Comment: It should but I do not have a valid NCPDP message to validate. What I need at least an XML representation of NCPDP so that I can turn it into NCPDP using Mirth and then try to turn it back using this code.

Comment: it is not possible to share NCPDP message code, btw thanks for reply. i'll try, and if i stuck then i'll tag you in new question.

Comment: Well, I've compiled a small package that re-use Mirth classes but I don't have a proper NCPDP to test. Simply copy-paste does not work because of non-printable characters.

Comment: Finally i am able to solve my answer, but thanks for spending your time and replying on question.

Comment: Can you please share It, Im triying to implement a java class to convert a NCPDP message to XML

Comment: The exact code is above. Everything else is adding dependencies.